# Автоматизация на виртульном хостиге

Tags: javascript, python, gulp, хостинг

Хочу для автоматизации части задач использовать Gulp или Python.
Но виртуальный хостинг утверждает что не доставит мне такой радости.
NPM тоже не разрешает.
Какие есть варианты, в данном контексте?
Замена хостинга, понятно, не рассматривается.

Есть мысль, например, удаленно по ftp заходить и там уже все делать.
Но не уверен что gulp так умеет. И все-равно, для работы скрипта надо будет отдельно VDS-ник брать или с локального компа загружать.
Хотелось бы бесплатное решение.

Comment: Замена хостинга на VDS — единственное адекватное решение, всё остальное костыли

Comment: Понимаю, но видимо придется рассмотреть костыли.
Руководство только 2 мес как переехало на новый хостинг.
И это битрикс хостинг - по слухам, для этой CMS нужен особо настроенный хостинг - поэтому не факт что и VDS было бы хорошим решением.

Comment: VDS даёт полный доступ к операционной системе, из чего неизбежно следует возможность особой настройки чего угодно (но, разумеется, настраивать нужно уметь)

Comment: Я понимаю - это простое и очевидное решение.
Но в этом вся соль вопроса - найти выход в текущих, ограниченных возможностях.